# tickAmount from apexcharts not working properly

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am trying to create a graph component for my react project. Although I specify `tickAmount` as 10 it is displaying  all numbers from 1 to 300. It should print only 10 data points:

```
       this.state = {
        //    data/:[],
        options: {
            chart: {
              id: "basic-bar"
            },
            xaxis: {
              categories: this.props.options, 
              interval: 50,
               width:1000,
              hideOverlappingLabels: true,
              tickAmount: 10,
              tickPlacement: 'between',
          },
        },
        //   options:,
          series:this.props.series
        };
      }
    render() {

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
             <Chart
              options={this.state.options}
              series={this.state.series}

              type="area"
              width="1000"
            />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Show whole code, how `Chart` looks like? Is it a library? Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: chart is library from apexcharts

Answer (score 1):

If you are providing numeric values in categories, you should also set the `xaxis.type: 'numeric'`

```
xaxis: {
    type: 'numeric',
    tickAmount: 10,
}
```

Comment: what if i want to use category type and i want only 10 data points

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you can use indeed the type = numeric, but then you can override the numbers with your own labels. Like this:

```js
xaxis: ApexXAxis = {
    type: 'numeric',
    tickPlacement: 'between',
    tickAmount: 4,
    decimalsInFloat: 0,
    overwriteCategories: ['0am  ', '7am', '3pm', '11pm'],
  };
```